# Is it possible to achieve multi row grouping in Prime NG?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I am trying to achieve something like in picture below using Prime NG multi row grouping.

[image: What i am trying to achive]
As per docs from Prime NG i should be able to do so,
https://primefaces.org/primeng/table,

[image: As per docs of Prime NG https://primefaces.org/primeng/table]

have any body done this before?  i have been trying with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowgroup-demo .

Thanks.